# Convert unsigned char* to NSData and vice-versa in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, unsigned

Just want to convert NSData to Byte and Byte to NSData using objective-c

```
    unsigned char* dataToByteArray = (unsigned char*) [data bytes];
    NSLog(@"Bytes is %@", dataToByteArray);
    
    NSData *datas = [NSData dataWithBytes:&dataToByteArray length:sizeof(dataToByteArray)];
    NSLog(@"Data is like%@", datas);
    NSLog(@"After convert bytes is %@", dataToByteArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Pass the buffer, not a pointer to the buffer, and length refers to the number of elements in the buffer, not to the size of the buffer pointer:

```objectivec
[NSData dataWithBytes:dataToByteArray length:[data length]]
```

`sizeof(dataToByteArray)` becomes the size of a pointer - 8 bytes. The initializer wants to know how many elements are in the buffer.

In addition, `%@` is only used to log Objective-C objects. `unsigned char *` is a C buffer, not an Objective-C object. (You can't log a C buffer directly with one "%something" since just the pointer does not contain enough information about, for example, how many elements and when to stop logging. It could just as well be a pointer to a single `unsigned char`. But you could use `%p` to log the pointer, `NSLog(@"first byte: %c", dataToByteArray[0])` to log the first byte, etc.)